# How size of Object is calculated while overloading new operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

using namespace std; 
class student 
{ 
    string name; 
    int age; 
public: 
    student() 
    { 
        cout<< "Constructor is called\n" ; 
    } 
    student(string name, int age) 
    { 
        this->name = name; 
        this->age = age; 
    } 
    void display() 
    { 
        cout<< "Name:" << name << endl; 
        cout<< "Age:" << age << endl; 
    } 
    void * operator new(size_t size) 
    { 
        cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl; 
        void * p = ::new student(); 
        //void * p = malloc(size); will also work fine 
    
        return p; 
    } 

    void operator delete(void * p) 
    { 
        cout<< "Overloading delete operator " << endl; 
        free(p); 
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    student * p = new student("Yash", 24); 
    p->display(); 
    delete p; 
    return 0;
}
```

When I run above program on Codeblock I got output of size as 28
(for this statement cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl; )
and also size of Object of student class is also 28 . How internally it is calculated ?

Comment: `sizeof(strudent)` is the size of all member variables, plus possible padding between the members.

Comment: I don't have much experience with overloading `nwe` and `delete` but shouldn't that `operator delete` use `::delete(p);` if `::new student();` is used?

Comment: The job of `operator new` is to allocate a block of memory of a specified size. So, as the comment says, `malloc(size)` will work, and it should be paired with `free(p)` in `operator delete`. If you want to use the global `operator new`, use `::operator new(size)` and pair it with `::operator delete(p)`. **Do not** use `::new student`. That constructs an **object** of type student. The `new` operator is not the same as `operator new`.